# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime : error while importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I built TensorFlow from source on my Ubuntu 17.04 32bit

I got this message while importing tensorflow

palash@ash:~$ python

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (32-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:10) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/palash/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/palash/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/palash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

```
my bazel info:
palash@ash:~$ bazel version
Build label: 0.4.5- (@non-git)
Build target: bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri May 19 01:31:26 2017 (1495157486)
Build timestamp: 1495157486
Build timestamp as int: 1495157486

my TensorFlow version : 1.0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in sense that perhaps it seems to be some compatibility error in tensorflow version 1.6 or above.

Downgrading the tensorflow to version 1.5 solved my problem.

To do this , I recommend to uninstall tensorflow version 1.8 by using `pip uninstall tensorflow` and again installing the version 1.5 by using `pip install tensorflow==1.5`.

In addition i would recommend that uninstall and reinstall keras library as well.

Comment: downgrade to 1.5 doesn't solve my issue, im on ubuntu 18

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly because of compatibility issues. For my Ubuntu 18 server, I had to use tensorflow==1.12 and it works now.

Try downgrading from latest version (1.12, now 26 Mar 2019) and see which version works.

This script tries a version (trytfver.sh):

```
pip uninstall tensorflow -y
pip install --user tensorflow==$1
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

Try it as following:

```
bash trytfver.sh 1.12
bash trytfver.sh 1.11
bash trytfver.sh 1.10
bash trytfver.sh 1.9
bash trytfver.sh 1.8
bash trytfver.sh ...
```

And see if any 'undefined symbol' errors appear, for example, I have error on 1.11.